# New Command: Default Optional Value?

Tags: beamer

Given the `beamer` class.

Consider `\newcommand<>...` within the preamble.

Its documentation mentions a "default optional value".

What is meant by this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic `\newcommand` syntax allows you to specify an "optional argument"; it is enclosed in square brackets. You can give a "default value" for this optional argument that will be used whenever you do not override it by providing the optional argument.  Compare:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\newcommand{⟨command name⟩}[⟨argument number⟩][⟨default optional value⟩]{⟨text⟩}

\newcommand{\forexample}[2][default optional value]{Do something with \textbf{#1} and \emph{#2}}

\begin{document}
  Use my \forexample{no optional argument given}

  Use my \forexample[this overrides the DOV]{optional argument given}
\end{document}
```

`beamer` extends this syntax with its "overlay specification" syntax -- i.e., the `<>`.  This allows you to make the command behave differently depending on what "overlay number" you are on.  For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
%\newcommand<>{⟨command name⟩}[⟨argument number⟩][⟨default optional value⟩]{⟨text⟩}

\newcommand<>{\forexample}[2][default optional value]{{\color#3{red}{Do something with \textbf{#1} and \emph{#2}}}}
% the extra braces in this example are to group the \color command.

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Use my: \forexample<1>{no optional argument given}

  Use my: \forexample<3>[this overrides the DOV]{optional argument given} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here, you should see the first line of the frame appear red on "overlay number 1", both appear black on number 2, and then the second line (but not the first) on number 3.

Comment: Nice explanation - I think I got it. Thank you!!

Comment: Besides what happens if it is left out: `\newcommand<>{\myexample}[2]{Slide #3: Argument #1 and #2}` vs. `\newcommand<>{\myexample}[2][]{Slide #3: Argument #1 and #2}`

Comment: @Freeze_S -- Well, in the first `\myexample`, you're not giving any optional arguments, so you need to use it like so: `\myexample{FIRST}{SECOND}`. In the second definition, you are specifying that the first argument is optional and it will expand to a space if you don't provide the first optional argument; compare: `\myexample{FIRST?}` and `\myexample[FIRST]{SECOND}`. A key point: in standard LaTeX2e, only the first argument can be optional. The packge `xparse` (which relies on LaTeX3) provides much greater flexibility.

Comment: Also: the `#3` is not doing anything as far as `beamer` is not concerned.